# How to change "cellsToShow" of Angular Carousel according to responsive changes

Tags: css, angular, responsive-design, tailwind-css, carousel

I am using `angular-responsive-carousel` for my angular project.

```
 <carousel [cellWidth]="'100%'" [objectFit]="'contain'" [margin]="40" [cellsToShow]="3">
      <div *ngFor="let service of services;" class="carousel-cell ">
        <div class="flex flex-col w-full">
          <img src={{service.image}} class="w-full" alt="" />
          <div class="service-shadow px-4 py-4 flex flex-col gap-2  rounded-b-xl">
            <p class="text-base font-bold ">{{service.title}}</p>
            <p class="text-sm text-[#00171BB2]">{{service.content}}</p>
            <div class="flex gap-2 items-center">
              <p class="text-[#2B3384] font-semibold">Learn More </p>
              <img src="/assets/images/icons/purple-arrow.svg" class="purple-arrow" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
 </carousel>
```

I don't know how to change [cellsToShow] according to responsive changes.

I am using Angular version 13 and Tailwind CSS.
There are breakpoints in Tailwind css.
`max-2xl: 1536px [cellsToShow]=4 max-xl:  1280px [cellsToShow]=3 max-lg:  1024px [cellsToShow]=2 max-md:  768px  [cellsToShow]=1`

Please let me know if anything is unclear in my explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eliseo's method appears to be working, however it does not seem to be functioning properly.
It adjusts according to changes in size, but when I switch from desktop to mobile size directly, it does not work.
Today, I discovered a method to detect the responsive breakpoint size. I added link below.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-size?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your carousel, but you can create an observable listen changes of the window resize, then use map to transform in a number 1,2,3,4

To listen the "resize" we use fromEvent rxjs operator

We need starts with some value, e.g. null, to execute almost one time

After "map" (really we check about "window.innerWidth) we return 1,2 3 or 4

Finally we use distictUntil because we don't need make anything if there're no change.

```
   cellsToShow$=fromEvent(window,'resize').pipe(
      startWith(null),
      map(_=>{
       if ((window.innerWidth)<768)
        return 1
       if ((window.innerWidth)<1024)
        return 2
       if ((window.innerWidth)<1280)
        return 3

        return 4
    }),
    distinctUntilChanged()
    )
```

Now you only need use async pipe

```
<carousel ... [cellsToShow]="cellsToShow$|async">
```